# Iframe não se ajusta vericalmente com o height 100%

Tags: css, iframe, height

Conforme código a seguir, o `<iframe>` não se ajusta verticalmente mesmo setando o atributo `height` como 100%.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://superlp.com.br" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Porque isso acontece? Como resolver?

Comment: Mas o `iframe` está utilizando 100% do elemento `div.panel-body`. Qual seria a sua necessidade?

Comment: Você quer que o painel se estenda a toda a página e o iframe o acompanhe?

Comment: Exatamente Andre Figueiredo. A página que fica dentro do iframe precisa aparecer por completa sem o scrollbar.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa pergunta no SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height

Comment: Como disse o Carlos, o `iframe` já está ocupando 100% da altura do elemento pai. O que resta a fazer, é forçar o elemento pai (`div`) a ocupar todo o espaço disponível.

Comment: Dá uma olhada http://jsfiddle.net/g206hbh9 e veja se é isso.

Comment: Amigo pode ser que tenha alguma div sua que limita ele antes, já olhou isto?

Answer (score 3):

tente isso:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<title>Documento sem t&iacute;tulo</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <iframe width="100%" style="position: absolute" height="100%" src="http://superlp.com.br" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Descobri uma solução muito simples: Onde tem `height="100%"`, substitua por `style="height:100vh"`.